# Rename file (Prefix) with full path?

Tags: shell, command-line, files, rename

I'd to Prefix my files (`.dat`) like this :

```
CLY_BIZ_COM_PERD.dat -> 20160622CLY_BIZ_COM_PERD.dat
```

I have tried the following:

```
key=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
for i in $(ls /Path/*.dat); do mv ${i} "${key}${i}" ;done
```

But this command *suffix* my files and not prefix it.
How can I do this?

Comment: Does it, really? Try it again (add an `echo` before the `mv` to echo what would have happened without actually doing it).

Comment: The result is : CLY_BIZ_COM_PERD.dat20160622 and not 20160622CLY_BIZ_COM_PERD.dat i need the second result

Comment: I doubt the loop works very well at all, as it would try to prefix the date to "/Path" instead of to the *.dat filenames themselves

Comment: Change `$(ls /Path/*.dat)` to `/Path/*.dat`

Comment: if you have `rename` command (written in Perl), first change to target directory and try `rename "s/(.*)/$(date +%Y%m%d)\1/" *.dat`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two changes to your current script:

1. don't [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); [instead rely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14725/117549) on the shell's globbing
2. because the files are in a subdirectory, either `cd` there first and run the loop, or use `basename` and `dirname` to pull out the directory and filename portions of the file before adding the prefix.

(Note: I also changed your "/Path" to "./Path" as I didn't want to create a root-level /Path directory. Same principles apply, though.

To set up some sample files:

```
mkdir Path && cd Path
touch CLY_BIZ_COM_PERD.dat jeff.dat a.dat c\ d.dat
cd ..
```

Here's a dry run:

```
for f in ./Path/*.dat
do 
  printf "mv '%s' '%s'\n" "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/${key}$(basename "$f")"
done
```

Output of the dry run:

```
mv './Path/a.dat' './Path/20160622a.dat'
mv './Path/c d.dat' './Path/20160622c d.dat'
mv './Path/CLY_BIZ_COM_PERD.dat' './Path/20160622CLY_BIZ_COM_PERD.dat'
mv './Path/jeff.dat' './Path/20160622jeff.dat'
```

Once you're content, do it for real:

```
for f in ./Path/*.dat
do 
  mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/${key}$(basename "$f")"
done
```

... and the result:

```
$ ls -1 Path
20160622a.dat
20160622c d.dat
20160622CLY_BIZ_COM_PERD.dat
20160622jeff.dat
```